# How to access an "anonymous" variable?

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7, tuples

There are some built-in functions that modify an object directly and return None.  An example is the `sort()` method of `list`, where the object itself is modified, ie sorted, but `None` is returned.

My question, how do I access `list(T).sort()`, where T is a tuple say T=(5,1,2,3,4,5), without first assigning `list(T)` to an explicit variable?

Comment: You cannot, but you can use `sorted()` to return the sorted object. What are you trying to do actually?

Comment: Just an academic exercise.  Joshua's answer is what I am seeking.

Comment: Maybe I'm blinded by practicality, but I'm not sure what's being asked here: at which point or stage do you want to "access" `list(T).sort()`? Which part of that expression do you want? What would you do with it?

Comment: Just an academic exercise, eg `sorted(list(T))[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `list.sort`, use the `sorted` builtin.

```
sorted(list(T))
```

Comment: Tuples can be directly sorted, no need to convert them to lists

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are immutables, so you cannot really change the order of elements, in-place. That is why, `tuple.sort` function *does not* exist. So you are left with two options.

1. Create a new tuple object with the elements sorted
2. Convert the tuple to an object which allows its elements to be sorted (e.g `list`s).

So, if you have a tuple, you can simply do

```
sorted(tupleObject)
```

to get a new *list* of sorted items. You can then convert that list object, to a tuple, if you want, like this

```
tuple(sorted(tupleObject))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python there are no variables in the traditional sense; there are names, that point to objects. Objects have values and types, names are just a way to refer to an object.

So names by themselves have no meaning - a name is only used when pointing to an object, otherwise it is perfectly fine to use an object "temporarily" without a name.

That's what is going on in your example. When you create `list(T)` and don't assign it to a name, there is no way for you to refer back to it.

To solve your actual problem, you can use `sorted()` directly on a tuple, but note that it will return a list:

```
>>> foo = sorted((0,1,4,3,5))
>>> foo
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

You still won't have access to the original unsorted tuple (unless you assign it first to a name).